# Onsen Carousel and Onsen Sliding Menu Collision

Tags: html, phonegap-build, onsen-ui

I have a sliding menu on my index.html

```html
<ons-sliding-menu
    menu-page="menu.html" main-page="welcome.html" side="left"
    var="menu" type="reveal" max-slide-distance="260px" swipable="false" swipe-target-width="50">
  </ons-sliding-menu>
```

But when I want to use a carousel after I the user goes to a new page with a `menu.setMainPage`

```html
<ons-list-item class="menu-item" ng-click="menu.setMainPage('connect.html', {closeMenu: true});">
    <ons-icon icon="ion-ios-people" fixed-width="true"></ons-icon>
    Connect
  </ons-list-item>
```

My carousel items seem to layered under the sliding menu. An example would be if I swipe the carousel item at a target-width="70" to try and move the carousel. It will not budge. It only moves with the index setting while the menu is sliding. Is there any way to make the carousel and sliding menu from the index function together? Or does the sliding menu have to be written on every page?

Answer (score 2):

Change  swipable="false" to swipeable="false"

Answer (score 0):

If your slider displays in it's own page, you can also try adding:

```
<ons-page sliding-menu-ignore="true">
```

This will override the sliding-menu's touch events.